# Is it possible to build a exe file from python code in Ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, wxpython, py2exe

Recently,I devoloped a software in Ubuntu with wxpython.And now I must build it to be a runnable exe file,I know that "py2exe" can do this job well if I install all the software in Windows.However,there are too many software to install in Windows.So, Is there any way to build a exe file from python code in Ubuntu?

Comment: To be clear: do you want to create a standalone executable for Ubuntu on Ubuntu or for Windows on Ubuntu?

Comment: @StefanS I want to create a standalone executable for Windows on Ubuntu

Answer (score 1):

You can use [PyInstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/) on [Wine](https://www.winehq.org/), PyInstaller runs fine in Wine. 
Check this [link](https://milkator.wordpress.com/2014/07/19/windows-executable-from-python-developing-in-ubuntu/).

Answer (score 0):

It is somewhat possible, yes. Years ago I've had a setup that involved a mingw cross compile setup, wine and cx_freeze. Sadly I do not remember specifics though.
The general problem you're facing, I think, is that all the tools you'll find need to be able to execute the python interpreter of the target OS.